# No route was found matching the URL and request method

Tags: plugins, php

I just created a test restapi function but it returns 404, please tell me what m doing wrong?

```
function draftusr( WP_REST_Request $request ) {

        $usr= 20;

        return $usr;
    }
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

  register_rest_route( 'draftusr/v2', '/draftusr', array(
        'methods' => array('GET','POST'),
        'callback' => 'draftusr',
    ) );

});
```

Comment: What’s the request you’re attempting?

Comment: "get"......i want that ....this url should return the value ----https://testsite.co/wp-json/draftusr/v2/draftusr  returns 20

Comment: At the end there are `});`, but no opening brackets. Is this code inside another function? What function?

Comment: code works perfect!! i just mistakenly pasted it on inactive theme's function.php...thanks for the help!